# Android Location Services - LocationListener does not work

Tags: android, service, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

OLD QUESTION:

I'm trying to get my device's location coordinates and I've followed all the steps that I've found in multiple areas while researching.  I've set up a LocationManager and used the requestLocationUpdates function that is tied to a LocationListener.  However, the LocationListener does not respond.  I've tried debugging as well as walking around outside in order for the onChangedLocation function to execute but nothing happens.  In debugging the requestLocationUpdates function for my LocationManager is executed but the LocationListener is never executed.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    locationListener = new myLocationListener();

    textView.setText("Longitude", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
    textView2.setText("Latitude", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, locationListener);
```

[requestLocationUpdates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr7Uz.png)

Above is the use of the requestLocationUpdates function.

```
private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Log.e("Latitude: ", "" + location.getLatitude());
        //Log.e("Longitude: ", "" + location.getLongitude());
        if(location != null)
        {
            textView.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
            textView2.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText("No Location", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
            textView2.setText("No Location", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onLocationChanged Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[myLocationListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulz82.png)

This is myLocationListener that implements LocationListener.  I've added a little bit of extra code for testing purposes.  The toast would never pop up so it appears as though this code is never executed.  If anyone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

NEW QUESTION:

After continuing on developing in this page while waiting for a response I noticed that it takes about a minute for the location services to actually begin working.  So, now my question is: how do I overcome the obstacle of a user having to wait to use the app?  I've seen apps that use location based content and it does not take that long.  I know that there is the getLastKnownLocation function but what if a user travels 50 miles before opening the app again?  Any help on this would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Each device which makes location request for gps, has to wait until gps hardware become warm. The wait time changes by device and where you stay. If you are inside a building, this time could take 1 minute or more.

To avoid wait, you can use getLastKnownLocation method, if returns a **cached** location, check location's date via getTime method. Determine yourself, is it old location by your scenario ?

if it's too old location, you have to make location request and wait.